# want to change the gps or location services setting programatically in android?

Tags: android, gps

I want to turn on and off gps programatically in android.

I tried using

```
boolean provider = Settings.Secure.putInt(this.getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED, 1);
```

but it requires a permission `"WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"` when I used this permission it gives me an error that only system apps can use this permission to write system settings.

Please tell me how I can change the settings programmatically.

Can I change my location services programatically?

Answer (score 0):

Please use this class:

```
public class GpsConnectionManager {

       @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
       public void turnGPSOn(Context context) {
               Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
               intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
               context.sendBroadcast(intent);

               String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
                               Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
               if (!provider.contains("gps")) { // if gps is disabled
                       final Intent poke = new Intent();
                       poke.setClassName("com.android.settings",
                                       "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
                       poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
                       poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
                       context.sendBroadcast(poke);

               }
       }


       public void turnGPSOff(Context context) {
               Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
               intent.putExtra("enabled", false);
               context.sendBroadcast(intent);
               // String provider =
               // Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),
               // Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
               // if (provider.contains("gps")) { // if gps is enabled
               // final Intent poke = new Intent();
               // poke.setClassName("com.android.settings",
               // "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
               // poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
               // poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
               // this.sendBroadcast(poke);
               // }
       }
}
```

and use these permissions:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

and from kitkat it wont work

Comment: your class reference example this can be passes as reference

Answer (score 0):

Prior to Android version 4.4. you cannot turn on or off gps programatically. Your will will fire this Exception starting from Kitkat version `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE`

You can not programmatically access GPS.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't, starting with Android 1.5. But you could redirect the user to the Location settings with :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
```